# Не деплоится приложение Vite React ни на GitHub ни на Netlify

Tags: развертывание

есть тестовое приложение,
https://github.com/Sergio-916/testprops.git
локально открывается и работает.
После деплоя выдает только пустой экран с дефолтной надписью Vite + React сверху на табе страницы. пробовал все возможные инструкции...